# Android fragment attach runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, runnable, android-handler

I have a fragment which contains a handler and a runnable. When the fragment is displayed the handler calls the runnable which callback's the handler. And from the runnable I update the view.

This works as I want.

Here is the situation where I have a problem :

When I open another application (like text messages or something else) and then I come back to my application, the fragment view is re-created and the runnable doesn't update the view anymore (When I leave my application at first, the runnable is still running).

I have looked at fragment lifecycle and read that the onCreateView method is always called when the fragment have to show up. But in my case this creates a new view which is not the one that the runnable is updating.

So how can I make the runnable still update the view when I come back to my application ?

Here is the code of the fragment :

```
public class RecordingFragment extends Fragment {


private Handler mHandler;
private TextView speedTextView;
private TextView rmpTextView;

/**
 * Thread that sends commands to OBD
 */
private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notifcationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notifcationBuilder.build());

        data = sendCommandsToOdb(mSocket);

        // Show data in UI
        if (data.get("Vehicle Speed") != null) {
            speedTextView.setText(data.get("Vehicle Speed").toString());
        }
        if (data.get("Engine RPM") != null) {
            rmpTextView.setText(data.get("Engine RPM").toString());
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_obd_recording, container, false);

    speedTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speedTextView);
    rmpTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rpmTextView);

   ...

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO : Refactor this with save instance

    // Récupération depuis les preferences
    handlerRunning = preferences.getBooleanValue("isHandlerRunning");

    if (!handlerRunning) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        handlerRunning = true;
        preferences.saveBoolean("isHandlerRunning", handlerRunning);
        openDeviceConnection(device);
    }
}

... 
}
```

Comment: That is just wrong. You don't call a runnable from a handler. You call a runnable and a Handler should be the Call backs. The reason for using a Handler is because the runnable Thread can't access the UI that is running from the main thread. So your problem might be on the Handler. Cause if the handler calls the the Thread, and you change focus on app. It may be causing the Interrupt call to your new Thread.

Comment: @Aizen It sounds like they are running the runnable on the main thread, i.e. `handler.post(runnable)` or `handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay)`

Comment: Omg. I think you're right. But Why would they do that?

Comment: There are times when it would be appropriate to do that... it's hard to tell if this is one of those times though, not enough info from the OP.

Comment: at this point I'd ask to share your code :)

Comment: ok, first of all, Runnable is not a Thread :) many are mistakenly things it is, but in fact Runnable runs in the Thread you may specify and it doesn't create a new Thread itself, so in your case you create your Handler object from UI thread so your Runnable will run in UI thread.

Comment: Then you're accessing Views from Runnable which is not good practice, and lastly I don't see where you actually run that runnable from? I see you create a runnable then `onActivityCreated` create a handler but neither of this var initiations will execute the code in the Runnable

Answer (score 0):

You either can make your fragment to retain `setRetainInstance(true)` or better run your runnable after the view is created - from `onActivityCreated()` callback
It's not a good idea to hold a reference to a view in different class (your Runnable implementation). The better architecture would be when Runnable will not directly modify the view

---EDIT after code shared---

For this concrete problem you're solving AsyncTask may be used, which handle a background Thread for long lasting operations and then post updates to UI thread. But even with that you still may leak your Views which you shouldn't. Easiest solution is to check if activity is still there before updating a view and discard changes if not, and then make your Fragment retain. I'll also add this is not my preferable solution, but to get things started try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setRetainInstance(true);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            notifcationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notifcationBuilder.build());
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return sendCommandsToOdb(mSocket);;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object data) {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()){
                return;
            }
            // Show data in UI
            if (data.get("Vehicle Speed") != null) {
                speedTextView.setText(data.get("Vehicle Speed").toString());
            }
            if (data.get("Engine RPM") != null) {
                rmpTextView.setText(data.get("Engine RPM").toString());
            }
        }
    }.execute();
  }
```

Comment: onActivityCreated() is not after the View is Created. it is onViewCreated(). "The better architecture would be when Runnable will not directly modify the view" This is somewhat true. Because it is impossible to point from another Thread to the MainThread UI.

Comment: To point to main thread: new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) which should work from any thread.

Comment: That is what I said at the top comment. You need Handler. But new Thread can't handle UI cause it is running on the MainThread. It is a MCHammer rule.

Comment: also `onActivityCreated()` is definitely called after `onCreateView` in the fragment lifecycle

Comment: yep, that is true. But it is on a latter part of the life cycle.

Comment: I just want to point out that, it is a Fragment call. So onCreateView() is what needed not onActivityCreated(). onActivityCreated() is already called by the Activity that is calling the Fragment. The topic is about Fragment.

Comment: And you said, onCreateView. I said onViewCreated().

Comment: @MaxCh I have tried with `setRetainInstance(true)` but it doesn't work as I want. Still have a new view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code works but not excatly as I want. The `doInBackground` return data but only once. And I have to get date every 5 seconds. I think if I want this with an asyncTask I'd need to do a loop somewhere but it wouldn't be the right way to do. I have started refactoring my code to use a Service which I think is the best way. Thanks again !!